# MySql or Cassandra

Tags: mysql, graph, cassandra, database

first of all I apologize for my English.

I have to store the following data structure:

n Nodes linked by m Edges (a Graph). 
Every node has a number of attributes(the same number and type for each node).

These nodes should also be linked to another set of objects (composed by a set of meta-datas(every object could have a different number of meta-datas) and a BLOB).

the number of nodes is 1000000 circa and the number of edges is 800000000

The point is: MySql or Cassandra?

Let me know if you need more details!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are graph databases that are designed specifically to store graph data, Neo4j is one example.

Answer (score 2):

Generally: if it has to be one of those two, do both and measure the performance. You can easily do this with both an SQL and a NoSQL approach. Also you didn't mention what queries you'll be running on the dataset (which greatly impacts the decision).

That said, nowadays I'd try to go for Cassandra whenever I have the possibility to do so, since the whole multi-node replication (and resulting fault tolerance) and all doesn't really work well with MySQL.